# Phone number masking for first three digit

Tags: jquery

I want to do masking on phone number my requirement is that you should start input form 8 only and second and the third digit will be from 0 to 9 but if the second digit is 2 then the third digit must be 2.

For example

```
(822) xxx-xxxx,
(833) xxx-xxxx,
(855) xxx-xxxx,
```

I took reference for masking form below link

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

But still not find any solution as per my requirement

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Masked Input plugin for jquery can be used to force a certain pattern on each character. So you can use the following masks

```
jQuery(function($){
   $.mask.definitions['8']='[8]';
   $("#eyescript").mask("(899)-999-9999");
});
```

This will force entering `8` in the first digit. This is half of your requirements. For forcing the second digit to match the third one, this won't help. You can use regex to validate the input.  Even better, with Reactive JS you can subscribe to the stream of the input character to validate it.